# Express + Mongoose: Cannot send response in callback

Tags: express, mongoose, callback, response, mongoose-schema

I've been frustrated with this issue for more than 24 hours and I've narrowed down the issue to this:

In the following code, I'm updating a MongoDB document using mongoose and upon a successful update, I return a json object via an express response. I get the following error when I try to call a response in the in the callback from the mongoose.

The update is successful in the database, I get the data back from the callback, and everything works as it should, except for sending the response saying everything is great.

I do not send a responses before this nor do I touch the `res` object in any way prior to sending. I am seeking help on how to send a response upon successful callback.

Error:

```
Updating user draftBooks
/home/samuel/Documents/Github/Moirai/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:419
        throw err;
        ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/samuel/Documents/Github/Moirai/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/samuel/Documents/Github/Moirai/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:164:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/samuel/Documents/Github/Moirai/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:250:15)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/samuel/Documents/Github/Moirai/server/lib/stories.js:105:13)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/samuel/Documents/Github/Moirai/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:162:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Promise.emit (/home/samuel/Documents/Github/Moirai/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:79:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/home/samuel/Documents/Github/Moirai/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:92:20)
```

Mongoose Schema:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// create user schema
var userSchema   = new Schema({
    user_id: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    draftBooks: [{book_id: String}]
});

// add draftBook
userSchema.methods.addDraftBook = function (book_id, callback) {
  return this.model('User').findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: this.user_id },  // search query
    { $push: { 'draftBooks': {'_id': book_id.toString()} } }, // update action
    { upsert: true },
    callback
  );
}
```

Express Route:

```
 router.route('/')
  .post((req, res, next) => {
   // other stuff that works great
   // req.storyData defined here
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
      // create update corresponding user
      console.log("Updating user draftBooks");
      // res.json({}) works outside of callback
      var userData = new user({ user_id: req.storyData.creator });
      userData.addDraftBook(req.storyData._id, (err, data) => {
        if (err){
           res.json({message: err});
        } else {
           res.json({message: "Should work"}); //gives error
        }
      });
  });
```

This has left me quite frustrated, I don't see anything syntactically wrong, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that this line :

```
res.json({message: "returns this response"})
```

runs before

```
res.json({message: "Gives error"}).
```

so you already set the json inside res, that why you get the error.
you cannot set the header twice. it doesn't make much sense to give value to res.json() twice (1 inside the callback and 1 outside)

why not do this :

```
     userData.addDraftBook(req.storyData._id, (err, data) => {
    if (!err)
        res.json({message: "successful data"})
    else
       res.json({message: "returns this response"})
  });
```

Comment: I added this line `res.json({message: "returns this response"})` to show that the response works outside of the callback. The error still occurs inside the callback. I will remove this to more clearly highlight the issue. Removing this line gives me this error `Cannot post /api/route` which interrupted my testing.

Comment: i have tried your code, replacing  userData.addDraftBook with other async function (i used "request") and it works good.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in the Error message printed out we find: `Can't set headers after they're sent.`

In your express route, you've written `res.json({});` twice. You appear to be receiving proper data back from the mongoose method. You then call `res.json({message: 'gives error'});`. This happens, as you say, event when called next(), because you are explicitly telling it to. Write an `if-else` statement where you've currently written that, to handle the error, like so:

```
blah blah (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Gives error' });
  } else {
    res.json({ success: true, data: data });
  }
});
```

Take out the last `res.json` call. You don't need it because you've already sent it back in the callback. In the context of the Express route, res is an object with lexical scope(I think), and since it's defined in the scope above, you have access to it in the nested functions. So when you send it in your callback, you're sending it for the whole POST request.

Comment: This structure mirrors my original setup, but doesn't solve the issue of the error occurring in the call back. Putting the `res.json` inside of conditional statements still causes the error. I added the response outside of the callback to show the response works here but not in the callback. I'll update this as it can be confusing (as it can be seen as the cause of error, but it is not).

Comment: Hmm, I'm at work and your schema method is strongly different from how I would normally write it, so I can't really take too much time figuring out the answer.

But why are you creating the variable `userData`? I would rework this to query your Mongo database to get the User, and then call the schema method directly on the fetched user. Promise chains or the async npm module can help you write clean code for this.

Lastly, I can indeed tell you that the 'Cannot set headers after they are sent' comes from sending `res.json` in multiple places. No other way it could have happened.

Comment: I'll look deeper into schema to see if I can determine a cause there. I've been toying with the idea of going to promises, I guess if I'll be sharing my code, I'll do so. I doubt a response is being sent though, I have a 404 response that runs at the very end of my route (commented out while debugging) and it checks `res.headersSent` to see if anything was sent. This is false, and along with getting no response (request side post fail) it makes me think there is no response actually sent.